# Boolean algebra is to classical logic like what is to relevant logic?

Tags: logic, terminology, lattice-orders, nonclassical-logic

### The Question:

> Boolean algebra is to classical logic like *what* is to [relevant logic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relevance_logic#:%7E:text=Relevance%20logic%2C%20also%20called%20relevant,of%20substructural%20or%20modal%20logics.)?

### Context:

I guess this is a [terminology](/questions/tagged/terminology) question, so there's not much I can add, except that I've been interested in paraconsistent logic for a long time.

Is the answer [de Morgan algebra](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan_algebra) or is that something else?

### Meta Question:

> Is the question well-formed?

Perhaps the question ought to be something like,

> Boolean algebra is to classical logic like *what* is to paraconsistent logic?

I don't know. But:

- If the answer to the Meta Question (MQ) is yes, then please answer the main question.
- If the answer to the MQ is no, then please feel free to tell me why and answer what I hope will be a clear intended question.
- If the answer to the MQ is nonclassical, please explain.

Comment: There are various notions of what an "algebraic semantics" for a given logic should be. See e.g. the Block/Pigozzi book [*Algebraizable logics*](https://bookstore.ams.org/memo-77-396/), or the SEP article on [algebraic propositional logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-algebraic-propositional/). The logics $\mathsf{R}$ and $\mathsf{RM}$ ("$\mathsf{R}$ + Mingle") are algebraizable, but the weaker logic $\mathsf{E}$ isn't (although I think it is protoalgebraizable).

Comment: Also, possibly of interest: [Duality for algebras of relevant logics](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00370149) by A. Urquart. As the title indicates, here the author goes further and gives a duality for these algebras. But this is only for a certain class of relevant logics—and a variety of algebras.

Comment: not every logic has an alegabraic counterpart like the one you are describing

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy Sure, but relevance logic **is** algebraizable. I think this is a fine question.