# Examples of finitely-valued logics that aren't algebraizable

Tags: logic, nonclassical-logic

I was reading [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4799982/boolean-algebra-is-to-classical-logic-like-what-is-to-relevant-logic) which asks about the equivalent of Boolean algebras for relevant logic.

In the comments, Noah Schweber mentions that the relevant logic E is not algebraizable. In the book *Algebraizable Logics*, Blok and Pigozzi also mention in the introduction that the Lewis Systems S1, S2, S3 are not algebraizable, although S4 and S5 are.

I have tried off and on over the years to read *Algebraizable Logics* and develop an understanding of what exactly algebraizable and protoalgebraizable logics are, without a lot of success. There are some other sources like [the SEP article on algebraic propositional logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-algebraic-propositional/#WhenLogiAlgeWhatDoesMean) that are very well written, but hard to use if you're trying to go from 0 to 60 rather than 60 to 100.

I'd like to try something different and *build up a collection of non-algebraizable logics that are simple as possible*.

No logic too simple.

For example, I'm pretty sure that the $\land$-only fragment of classical logic is not algebraizable because you can't cobble together $\land$-s to make a formula that looks like implication or equivalence.

This $\land$-only logic, though, doesn't exercise any interesting facets of the definition of algebraizability and thus isn't a good test case for probing it.

Comment: Czelakowski's book [*Protoalgebraic logics*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-94-017-2807-2) (and the general search term "protoalgebraic logic") might be a good source.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example.

```
∧  F U T    ¬
F  F F F    F  T
U  F U U    U  U
T  F U T    T  F
```

If the designated truth values are $T$ and $U$, then the equation $\lnot(a \land \lnot a) \approx a$ holds for precisely the designated truth values and thus the logic is algebraizable.

If the sole designated truth value is $T$, then there is no set of equations identifying the designated truth values. $U$ is a fixed point of both connectives $\land$ and $\lnot$ and there are no truth value constants, therefore any possible set of equations will include $U$. **Thus this logic is not algebraizable.**

---

From what I can gather, being algebraizable is equivalent to having a matrix semantics in which the set of designated truth values is definable with a finite set of equations.

More precisely,

Let $L$ be an algebraic signature with functions $f^\to$ corresponding to $\to$ and likewise for each connective.

Let $\text{EQN}$ be the equational fragment of FOL, where the sole connective is $=$ and the sole quantifier is $\forall$. $\text{EQN}$ does not have higher order equivalences (so no $\leftrightarrow$ connective), unlike [equational logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equational_logic) on Wikipedia

Let $D(a)$ be a finite set of well-formed $L$-formulas whose open variables are among $\{a\}$. Intuitively, $D(a)$ expresses that $a$ *has a designated truth value*.

Let $\Delta$ be a not necessarily finite set of sentences. Intuitively, $\Delta$ is a preamble establishing the equivalences in the logic such as double negation being equivalent to the absence of any negation: $[\forall x](f^\lnot(f^\lnot(x)) = x)$, which corresponds to $\lnot\lnot x \approx x$ in traditional notation.

A deductive system $S = (\mathcal{L}, \vdash_S)$ with $\vdash_S$ being a consequence relation is algebraizable if and only if there exists a set of sentences $\Delta$ and a finite set of formulas $D(a)$ such that for all $\Gamma, \psi$, $\Gamma \vdash \psi$ if and only if $\Delta, \{ D(\varphi) : \varphi \in \Gamma \} \models_{\text{EQN}} D(\psi)$.

This is a little different from the presentation in Blok and Pigozzi. Here $\Delta$ serves the role that the quasivariety $K$ of $L$-algebras does. I think this notion is the same as the one in Blok and Pigozzi, but **at the moment I don't have a proof**.

In other words, when looking at a matrix semantics for a logic, that logic is algebraizable if and only if **the set of designated truth values is definable using a finite set of equations**.

However, the **definition of algebraizability is more general than this**, it takes as an input a consequence relation, not a matrix semantics. The matrix semantics is paraphrased away, but it is lurking there in the background and motivates the definition of algebraizability.